# Graph_helper.py Send on behalf of another user - Django

Tags: django, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have the following code (graph_helper.py), which I copied when completing the Microsoft Graph - Django.

The create_event and create_online_event functions works fine for the logged in user. What I ideally need is rather than the calendar events coming from the logged in user, they come from another shared mailbox they have access to.

I have tried adding into additional properties including organiser and isOrganiser but these didnt work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0

I also tried editing the below requests.post in the create_events to include the calendar id I want the invites to come from but still no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-event-in-shared-delegated-calendar?tabs=http#code-try-0

```
requests.post('{0}/me/events'.format(graph_url),
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(new_event))
```

Appreciate any help I can get with this issue. I know I can sign in as the shared account but will be better if I can set this up to allow sending on behalf of the logged in user.

**Graph_helper.py**

```
import requests
import json

graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'

def get_user(token):
  # Send GET to /me
  user = requests.get(
    '{0}/me'.format(graph_url),
    headers={
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)
    },
    params={
      '$select': 'displayName,mail,mailboxSettings,userPrincipalName'
    })
  # Return the JSON result
  return user.json()

def get_calendar_events(token, start, end, timezone):
  # Set headers
  headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
    'Prefer': 'outlook.timezone="{0}"'.format(timezone)
  }

  # Configure query parameters to
  # modify the results
  query_params = {
    'startDateTime': start,
    'endDateTime': end,
    '$select': 'subject,organizer,start,end',
    '$orderby': 'start/dateTime',
    '$top': '50'
  }

  # Send GET to /me/events
  events = requests.get('{0}/me/calendarview'.format(graph_url),
    headers=headers,
    params=query_params)

  # Return the JSON result
  return events.json()

# Basic lookup for mapping Windows time zone identifiers to
# IANA identifiers
# Mappings taken from
# https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml
zone_mappings = {
  'Dateline Standard Time': 'Etc/GMT+12',
  'UTC-11': 'Etc/GMT+11',
  'Aleutian Standard Time': 'America/Adak',
  'Hawaiian Standard Time': 'Pacific/Honolulu',
  'Marquesas Standard Time': 'Pacific/Marquesas',
  'Alaskan Standard Time': 'America/Anchorage',
  'UTC-09': 'Etc/GMT+9',
  'Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)': 'America/Tijuana',
  'UTC-08': 'Etc/GMT+8',
  'Pacific Standard Time': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  'US Mountain Standard Time': 'America/Phoenix',
  'Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)': 'America/Chihuahua',
  'Mountain Standard Time': 'America/Denver',
  'Central America Standard Time': 'America/Guatemala',
  'Central Standard Time': 'America/Chicago',
  'Easter Island Standard Time': 'Pacific/Easter',
  'Central Standard Time (Mexico)': 'America/Mexico_City',
  'Canada Central Standard Time': 'America/Regina',
  'SA Pacific Standard Time': 'America/Bogota',
  'Eastern Standard Time (Mexico)': 'America/Cancun',
  'Eastern Standard Time': 'America/New_York',
  'Haiti Standard Time': 'America/Port-au-Prince',
  'Cuba Standard Time': 'America/Havana',
  'US Eastern Standard Time': 'America/Indianapolis',
  'Turks And Caicos Standard Time': 'America/Grand_Turk',
  'Paraguay Standard Time': 'America/Asuncion',
  'Atlantic Standard Time': 'America/Halifax',
  'Venezuela Standard Time': 'America/Caracas',
  'Central Brazilian Standard Time': 'America/Cuiaba',
  'SA Western Standard Time': 'America/La_Paz',
  'Pacific SA Standard Time': 'America/Santiago',
  'Newfoundland Standard Time': 'America/St_Johns',
  'Tocantins Standard Time': 'America/Araguaina',
  'E. South America Standard Time': 'America/Sao_Paulo',
  'SA Eastern Standard Time': 'America/Cayenne',
  'Argentina Standard Time': 'America/Buenos_Aires',
  'Greenland Standard Time': 'America/Godthab',
  'Montevideo Standard Time': 'America/Montevideo',
  'Magallanes Standard Time': 'America/Punta_Arenas',
  'Saint Pierre Standard Time': 'America/Miquelon',
  'Bahia Standard Time': 'America/Bahia',
  'UTC-02': 'Etc/GMT+2',
  'Azores Standard Time': 'Atlantic/Azores',
  'Cape Verde Standard Time': 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde',
  'UTC': 'Etc/GMT',
  'GMT Standard Time': 'Europe/London',
  'Greenwich Standard Time': 'Atlantic/Reykjavik',
  'Sao Tome Standard Time': 'Africa/Sao_Tome',
  'Morocco Standard Time': 'Africa/Casablanca',
  'W. Europe Standard Time': 'Europe/Berlin',
  'Central Europe Standard Time': 'Europe/Budapest',
  'Romance Standard Time': 'Europe/Paris',
  'Central European Standard Time': 'Europe/Warsaw',
  'W. Central Africa Standard Time': 'Africa/Lagos',
  'Jordan Standard Time': 'Asia/Amman',
  'GTB Standard Time': 'Europe/Bucharest',
  'Middle East Standard Time': 'Asia/Beirut',
  'Egypt Standard Time': 'Africa/Cairo',
  'E. Europe Standard Time': 'Europe/Chisinau',
  'Syria Standard Time': 'Asia/Damascus',
  'West Bank Standard Time': 'Asia/Hebron',
  'South Africa Standard Time': 'Africa/Johannesburg',
  'FLE Standard Time': 'Europe/Kiev',
  'Israel Standard Time': 'Asia/Jerusalem',
  'Kaliningrad Standard Time': 'Europe/Kaliningrad',
  'Sudan Standard Time': 'Africa/Khartoum',
  'Libya Standard Time': 'Africa/Tripoli',
  'Namibia Standard Time': 'Africa/Windhoek',
  'Arabic Standard Time': 'Asia/Baghdad',
  'Turkey Standard Time': 'Europe/Istanbul',
  'Arab Standard Time': 'Asia/Riyadh',
  'Belarus Standard Time': 'Europe/Minsk',
  'Russian Standard Time': 'Europe/Moscow',
  'E. Africa Standard Time': 'Africa/Nairobi',
  'Iran Standard Time': 'Asia/Tehran',
  'Arabian Standard Time': 'Asia/Dubai',
  'Astrakhan Standard Time': 'Europe/Astrakhan',
  'Azerbaijan Standard Time': 'Asia/Baku',
  'Russia Time Zone 3': 'Europe/Samara',
  'Mauritius Standard Time': 'Indian/Mauritius',
  'Saratov Standard Time': 'Europe/Saratov',
  'Georgian Standard Time': 'Asia/Tbilisi',
  'Volgograd Standard Time': 'Europe/Volgograd',
  'Caucasus Standard Time': 'Asia/Yerevan',
  'Afghanistan Standard Time': 'Asia/Kabul',
  'West Asia Standard Time': 'Asia/Tashkent',
  'Ekaterinburg Standard Time': 'Asia/Yekaterinburg',
  'Pakistan Standard Time': 'Asia/Karachi',
  'Qyzylorda Standard Time': 'Asia/Qyzylorda',
  'India Standard Time': 'Asia/Calcutta',
  'Sri Lanka Standard Time': 'Asia/Colombo',
  'Nepal Standard Time': 'Asia/Katmandu',
  'Central Asia Standard Time': 'Asia/Almaty',
  'Bangladesh Standard Time': 'Asia/Dhaka',
  'Omsk Standard Time': 'Asia/Omsk',
  'Myanmar Standard Time': 'Asia/Rangoon',
  'SE Asia Standard Time': 'Asia/Bangkok',
  'Altai Standard Time': 'Asia/Barnaul',
  'W. Mongolia Standard Time': 'Asia/Hovd',
  'North Asia Standard Time': 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk',
  'N. Central Asia Standard Time': 'Asia/Novosibirsk',
  'Tomsk Standard Time': 'Asia/Tomsk',
  'China Standard Time': 'Asia/Shanghai',
  'North Asia East Standard Time': 'Asia/Irkutsk',
  'Singapore Standard Time': 'Asia/Singapore',
  'W. Australia Standard Time': 'Australia/Perth',
  'Taipei Standard Time': 'Asia/Taipei',
  'Ulaanbaatar Standard Time': 'Asia/Ulaanbaatar',
  'Aus Central W. Standard Time': 'Australia/Eucla',
  'Transbaikal Standard Time': 'Asia/Chita',
  'Tokyo Standard Time': 'Asia/Tokyo',
  'North Korea Standard Time': 'Asia/Pyongyang',
  'Korea Standard Time': 'Asia/Seoul',
  'Yakutsk Standard Time': 'Asia/Yakutsk',
  'Cen. Australia Standard Time': 'Australia/Adelaide',
  'AUS Central Standard Time': 'Australia/Darwin',
  'E. Australia Standard Time': 'Australia/Brisbane',
  'AUS Eastern Standard Time': 'Australia/Sydney',
  'West Pacific Standard Time': 'Pacific/Port_Moresby',
  'Tasmania Standard Time': 'Australia/Hobart',
  'Vladivostok Standard Time': 'Asia/Vladivostok',
  'Lord Howe Standard Time': 'Australia/Lord_Howe',
  'Bougainville Standard Time': 'Pacific/Bougainville',
  'Russia Time Zone 10': 'Asia/Srednekolymsk',
  'Magadan Standard Time': 'Asia/Magadan',
  'Norfolk Standard Time': 'Pacific/Norfolk',
  'Sakhalin Standard Time': 'Asia/Sakhalin',
  'Central Pacific Standard Time': 'Pacific/Guadalcanal',
  'Russia Time Zone 11': 'Asia/Kamchatka',
  'New Zealand Standard Time': 'Pacific/Auckland',
  'UTC+12': 'Etc/GMT-12',
  'Fiji Standard Time': 'Pacific/Fiji',
  'Chatham Islands Standard Time': 'Pacific/Chatham',
  'UTC+13': 'Etc/GMT-13',
  'Tonga Standard Time': 'Pacific/Tongatapu',
  'Samoa Standard Time': 'Pacific/Apia',
  'Line Islands Standard Time': 'Pacific/Kiritimati'
}

def get_iana_from_windows(windows_tz_name):
  if windows_tz_name in zone_mappings:
    return zone_mappings[windows_tz_name]
  else:
    # Assume if not found value is
    # already an IANA name
    return windows_tz_name

def create_event(token, subject, start, end, attendees=None, body=None, timezone='UTC'):
  # Create an event object
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0
  new_event = {
    'subject': subject,
    'start': {
      'dateTime': start,
      'timeZone': timezone
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': end,
      'timeZone': timezone
    },

  }

  if attendees:
    attendee_list = []
    for email in attendees:
      # Create an attendee object
      # https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/attendee?view=graph-rest-1.0
      attendee_list.append({
        'type': 'required',
        'emailAddress': { 'address': email }
      })

    new_event['attendees'] = attendee_list

  if body:
    # Create an itemBody object
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/itembody?view=graph-rest-1.0
    new_event['body'] = {
      'contentType': 'text',
      'content': body
    }

  # Set headers
  headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  requests.post('{0}/me/events'.format(graph_url),
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(new_event))

def create_online_event(token, subject, start, end, attendees=None, body=None, timezone='UTC'):
  # Create an event object
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0

  new_event = {
    'subject': subject,
    'start': {
      'dateTime': start,
      'timeZone': timezone
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': end,
      'timeZone': timezone
    },
    "isOnlineMeeting": True,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
  }

  if attendees:
    attendee_list = []
    for email in attendees:
      # Create an attendee object
      # https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/attendee?view=graph-rest-1.0
      attendee_list.append({
        'type': 'required',
        'emailAddress': { 'address': email }
      })

    new_event['attendees'] = attendee_list

  if body:
    # Create an itemBody object
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/itembody?view=graph-rest-1.0
    new_event['body'] = {
      'contentType': 'text',
      'content': body,
      "contentType": "HTML"
    }

  # Set headers
  headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  requests.post('{0}/me/events'.format(graph_url),
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(new_event))
```